# Javascript get key of multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've the following array:

```
$test[$iterator][1][2]['name']
```

I have a function that needs to get `$iterator` of that array when `['name'] == 'value';`

So how can I use Javascript to get the given `$iterator`?

Also, I did look at other questions, but I'm not sure if their answers apply to my question.

Comment: PHP or JavaScript? The `$` seems a little strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var $iterator;
for (var i = 0; i < $test.length; i++) {
    if ($test[i][1][2]['name'] == 'value')
    {
        $iterator = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.  I was trying some jQuery.methods, and they weren't working. 
Thanks alot! 

Also, yeah, I have a bad habit about sometimes using php variable names in my javascript code.